# Cancel previous call of Google Maps geocode method

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, callback, google-geocoder

I am implementing a autocomplete with Javascript and Google Maps geocode method (using keyup event on input) and some times I receive the previous search before the actual one.

My intention is to cancel previous call if it hasn't finished. Can anybody can help me?

```
getAddressLatLng : function(text,callback) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     geocoder.geocode({
         address : text,
         region : Utils.getRegion()
     },
     function(results, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             callback(results);
         }
     });
},
```

Comment: No good idea to use key-events to start geocoding, this may reach your quota very soon.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a global request counter, and only perform your callback behavior if it does not increase. e.g.

```
var requests = 0;
...
    getAddressLatLng : function(text,callback) {
        var requestNum;
        requests++;
        requestNum = requests;
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
         geocoder.geocode({
             address : text,
             region : Utils.getRegion()
         },
         function(results, status) {
             if(requestNum != requests) return;
             if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                 callback(results);
             }
         });
    },
```

I would also suggest debouncing/throttling your function so you don't waste bandwidth generating unnecessary requests ([underscore has convenient functions for doing this](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce)).